# Double possessive of a single noun

Tags: possessives

I am writing a question for a quiz.  I need some advice on what the "right" way to word the question.

The question follows a short passage in a foreign language.  The question is asking about the color of the speaker's father's car.

As I have it written, the question reads: 
"What color is the speaker's father's car?"

Is there a more concise way to ask the question?

Comment: The question is fine as it stands. Besides, deciphering the question can be part of the fun of the quiz. :)

Comment: Less concise, but I think easier to parse: "The speaker's father owns a car. What colour is it?"

Comment: Speaker's Father's car. What color? Although arguably the 'what' could be dropped.

Answer (score 1):

What color is the car of the speaker's father?
But if the passage talks of two cars owned by the speaker and his father, I think your original question would be better.